# Getting the newly selected option value with React Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have my select:

```
<Select
  options={[
    { value: "1", label: "1" },
    { value: "2", label: "2" },
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "6", label: "6" },
  ]}
  name="mySelect"
  ref={mySelect}
  instanceId="mySelect"
  defaultValue=""
  onChange={() => getSelect(mySelect)}
/>
```

I have my function:

```
function getSelect(val) {
    console.log(val.current.props.value["value"])
  }
```

This logs the previous value, I understand why this happens but I can't think of another way to attempt this. Is there something similar to afterChange?

Comment: Could you explain the problem? What is not working?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current value, you should be using the value from the onChange instead. You don't need ref for this

```
<Select
  options={[
    { value: "1", label: "1" },
    { value: "2", label: "2" },
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "6", label: "6" },
  ]}
  name="mySelect"
  ref={mySelect}
  instanceId="mySelect"
  defaultValue=""
  onChange={(value) => getSelect(value)}
/>

function getSelect(val) {
    console.log(val)
}
```

Comment: val should be value but this is what I needed thank you

Comment: Good catch. I've updated the answer for future references.

Answer (score 0):

It':

```
val.current.value
```

Not:

```
val.current.props.value
```

And since you are using ref so you don't need to send it throw parameter to handleChange function:

```
  const mySelect = React.useRef(null);

  function handleChange() {
    if (mySelect.current) {
      console.log(mySelect.current.value);
    }
  }
......
<Select
  options={[
    { value: "1", label: "1" },
    { value: "2", label: "2" },
    { value: "3", label: "3" },
    { value: "4", label: "4" },
    { value: "5", label: "5" },
    { value: "6", label: "6" },
  ]}
  name="mySelect"
  ref={mySelect}
  instanceId="mySelect"
  defaultValue=""
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```